# Why doe this JS array not reduce in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a Vuex store which has a roster object.  The roster object has an array of subteam objects.  Each subteam object has an array of position objects.  How do I count the total positions?

See the following getter:

```
totalPositions : function (state) {
    let reducer = (accumulator, subteam) => accumulator + subteam.positions.length;
    return state.roster.subteams.reduce(reducer);
}
```

When I log the result, I get something like:

```
"[object Object]33010600000000000000000000000000000"
```

The digits in the string closely resemble the actual lengths of the position arrays, but not exactly.  I tried using parseInt (even though array.length should be an integer):

```
let reducer = (accumulator, subteam) => {
    return accumulator + parseInt(subteam.positions.length,10);
};
```

It didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must pass an initial value to the [`reduce` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
totalPositions : function (state) {
    const reducer = (accumulator, subteam) => accumulator + subteam.positions.length;
    return state.roster.subteams.reduce(reducer, 0);
}
```

> If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used.

Since the `subteam` looks like an object, it is transformed into string `[object Object]` in the addition.

```
const obj = {};
console.log(obj + 13)
// => "[object Object]13"
```

Then say `"[object Object]3" + 3` is `"[object Object]33"`, etc. as the accumulator is now a string.

---

I really recommend you watch the [**Wat** lightning talk](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)  by Gary Bernhardt from CodeMash 2012.

Comment: You are a legend Emile.